eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();") is failing in testing sandbox with error [$A is not defined], but works fine in dev sandbox
So we have a lightning button which calls a LWC component. This LWC component opens up in a popup window with Save and Cancel button.
Now on the click of Cancel button the below LWC js code is called:
eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());

When I click on Cancel button, instead of closing the popup window I get the below error, saying:
[$A is not defined]

But the strange part is, the above syntax works fine in my dev sandbox but DOES NOT work in my one level up test sandbox. Any suggestions here?

Lightning Web Security must have been enabled in the org facing this error. eval() is not allowed in LWC components when LWS (Lightning Web Security) is enabled under Salesforce Setup > Session Settings.

Probably the Lightning Web Security is enabled on the test sandbox, as it blocks access to $A variable.
You can find more info under the links below:

Limitation of $A Global Variable in Aura Components
Lightning Web Security FAQ
Salesforce Global Variables Blocked by LWS

